# Visual Studio - Weird Characters output

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am running this program in visual studio 2013, but it is printing strange characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    char first[11];
    char second[11];
}INFO;

char * str1;
char * str2;
int num;

void bar_function(INFO info)
{
    str1 = info.first;
    str2 = info.second;
    num = 100;
    printf("%s %s\n", str1, str2);
}

void print()
{
    printf("%s %s\n", str1, str2);
    printf("%d\n", num);
}

int main(void)
{
    INFO info;
    strcpy(info.first, "Hello ");
    strcpy(info.second, "World!");

    bar_function(info);
    print();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

in ***bar_function*** function, I am assigning values to global variables and printing the strings. It is printing correct output. But when I am printing same strings in ***print*** function, It is printing weird characters in output in ***visual studio 2013***. Meanwhile ***num*** variable is printing correct value in ***print*** function. Here is the output for the same.

> Hello  World!
>
> ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠─²F ╠╠╠╠╠─²F
>
> 100

Also, same program is working perfectly in Codeblocks and printing correct values.

I am not able to understand this weird behavior in visual studio. Can someone explain this.

Comment: Change `void bar_function(INFO info)` to `void bar_function(INFO & info)` or copy the c-strings in bar_function. Remember info is a local variable to bar_function() when it goes out of scope the c-strings no longer exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `bar_function` the variable `info` is a *local variable*, and as such it will go out of scope and cease to exist when the function returns.

That means the pointers to the arrays will become invalid, and dereferencing them will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Since you *claim* to be programming C++ you should use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for strings, instead of pointers or arrays. And of course avoid global variables as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I confused with assignment operator in str1 = info.first;